# How to reload Page in blackberry cascades QML

Tags: qt, blackberry, qml, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

in my blackberry cascades app I have created a page using qml that loads data from backend after making an API call and works fine. But after I move to next page and come back I need to reload the data. i.e perform the onCreationCompleted operation again. Also the Qt.pageDef shows undefined after I come back so I guess if I could reload the page, it would work fine. I'm new to blackberry cascades, can anyone tell me what should I do to reload this page again and re-initialise Qt.pageDef?

```
Page {
        id: homePage

        Container {
           id:contactListView
                    //Some code to create listview

                  onCreationCompleted:
                    {
                      Qt.pageDef = contactListView;
                     fetchInfo();
                     }

                    fetchInfo()
                     {
                      //make api call and fill listview
                       }
                  }
    }
```

Comment: Could you post the code where you push that next page to the screen?

Comment: I have a button that pushes to next page, like  onClicked: {      
            nav.push(profilePageDefinition.createObject());
        } profilePageDefinition is ComponentDefinition in attached objects.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, there are some part of code missing as you show us a Page but you seem to push a new page from a NavigationPane.

Add this to your NavigationPane :
    onPopTransitionEnded: {
        fetchInfo()
    }

Comment: I have a main.qml from where I push to this page. There is no navigation page in the homepage I can only access the paneproperties